# Swift 5.1 generic usage in subclass

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift5

I have the following data model class to represent a MyDataModel:

```
  public class MyDataModel <T> : Codable, Comparable where T:Codable {

   ...
  }
```

Next I implement a view that holds an instance of MyDataModel. I can not obviously hold a generic parameter in the subclass of UIView so I try to workaround it as follows:

```
 protocol MyDataProtocol {
    associatedtype T:Codable
     var dataParam:T { get set }
 }

  public class MyDataView: UIView {

      public var myData:some MyDataProtocol?

  }
```

But I get an error

```
  An 'opaque' type must specify only 'Any', 'AnyObject', protocols, and/or a base class
```

So I can use Any? as type for MyDataProtocol but that will still not tell me the param type of MyDataModel. I am wondering what is the solution here and right way to handle this issue.

Comment: "I can not obviously hold a generic parameter in the subclass of UIView" Really? Why not?

Comment: I also don't understand what prevents you from having `public class MyDataView<T>: UIView { public var myData: T }`

Comment: @KirilS. The problem is I need to store these data views in an array in another class. Then I will need to declare that class as generic as well and the chain goes on. It makes things more complex from my previous experience (already tried it elsewhere and it was a mess).

Comment: @KirilS. And the class which holds these data views, to make things complex, it can hold data views of different subtypes T at the same time. How will that work(even if it makes things complicated)?

Comment: @Sweeper As explained in my comments above, it is not feasible.

Comment: You can store it as array of whatever is the "nature" of items you need to manipulate inside the array, independent of class's own type or generics (e.g. `var array: [UIView]` if you need those objects as UIViews in array). 
If you are struggling that in the array you have to think of item as both, UIView, and specific type, then you need to review your approach, and possibly separate View from model, so that view would contain a specific type, while model would be based on generics

Answer (score 2):

You should set an object for myData property and the error wouldn't show.

```
// Protocol example

public protocol MyDataProtocol {
    var dataParam: Codable? { get set }
}

class MyData: MyDataProtocol {
    var dataParam: Codable?
    init() {}
}

public class MyDataView: UIView {
    public var myData: MyDataProtocol?

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        print("test")
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

MyDataView(frame: .zero)


// Opaque example

public protocol MyDataProtocol {
    associatedtype T
    var dataParam: T? { get set }
}

class MyData: MyDataProtocol {
    var dataParam: Codable?
    init() {}
}

public class MyDataView: UIView {
    public var myData: some MyDataProtocol = MyData()

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        print("test")
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

MyDataView(frame: .zero)
```

Comment: Does not build!

Comment: @DeepakSharma, check my comment again please, I uploaded a screenshot and you can see it was built for me.

Comment: Ok I see it builds with Codable, but not with any proprietary protocols defined by me. It gives error - *Protocol 'Interpolatable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements*

Comment: @DeepakSharma, my post was updated. Because you try to combinate it, it doesn't work in this way. You should choose one way. If you use opaque, you must return a current object. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OpaqueTypes.html

Comment: @Deepak Sharma: if you get that error, than either you re-think what you are doing (@Sweeper comment was spot on…) otherwise you'll need to created type-erased concrete types for your protocols with associated type.